# Is this the correct way to call a component method inside mxml

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, itemrenderer

I'm hacking my way through learning Flex and have found some strange behaviour. When I try to compile my code, I'm thrown this error - Error: Call to a possibly undefined method updateStory. I've used method calls in this way before, and can't spot what's going wrong in this case. Here's the code for the component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    public var storyCards:ArrayCollection;

    private function updateStory():void
    {
       trace("success");
    }   

    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:TileList dataProvider="{storyCards}" >

    <mx:itemRenderer>

      <mx:Component>

    <mx:HBox>
      <mx:Label />
      <mx:TextInput keyUp="updateStory()" />
      <mx:TextArea text="{data.notes}" />
    </mx:HBox>

      </mx:Component>

    </mx:itemRenderer>

  </mx:TileList>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is with the mx:Component parent tag.

from [the docs:](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mxml/component.html)

> The <**mx:Component**> tag defines a new
>   scope within an MXML file, where the
>   local scope of the item renderer or
>   item editor is defined by the MXML
>   code block delimited by the
>   <**mx:Component**> and <**/mx:Component**>
>   tags. To access elements outside of
>   the local scope of the item renderer
>   or item editor, you prefix the element
>   name with the outerDocument keyword.

So you need to make 'updateStory' public and add the outerdocument keyword, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    public var storyCards:ArrayCollection;

    public function updateStory():void
    {
       trace("success");
    }       
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:TileList dataProvider="{storyCards}" >
       <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox>
                 <mx:Label />
                 <mx:TextInput keyUp="outerDocument.updateStory()" />
                 <mx:TextArea text="{data.notes}" />
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:TileList>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: To add a bit more detail...  
mx:Component really just creates a new class that gets instantiated once for every visible item in a List-based control.  outerDocument is a reference in that class to the object which created the class.

Comment: +1 Your solution set me in the right direction. I used parentDocument instead of outerDocument in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also dispatch an Event from the ItemRenderer Component, and add a Listener in the main document. This is useful should you want to port the ItemRenderer Component to a separate MXML Component file.

Here it is with your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var storyCards:ArrayCollection;

        private function updateStory():void
        {
           trace("success");
        }       

        ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:TileList dataProvider="{storyCards}" myEvent="updateStory();">

        <mx:itemRenderer>

          <mx:Component>
            <mx:Metadata>
                [Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
            </mx:Metadata>

        <mx:HBox>
          <mx:Label />
          <mx:TextInput keyUp="dispatchEvent(new Event('myEvent', true))" />
          <mx:TextArea text="{data.notes}" />
        </mx:HBox>

          </mx:Component>

        </mx:itemRenderer>

  </mx:TileList>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Here's how you would use it in a separate MXML Component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        public var storyCards:ArrayCollection;

        private function updateStory():void
        {
           trace("success");
        }       

        ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:TileList dataProvider="{storyCards}" myEvent="updateStory();" itemRenderer="StoryEditor" />
</mx:Canvas>

StoryEditor.mxml:

<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
    </mx:Metadata>

    <mx:Label />

    <mx:TextInput keyUp="dispatchEvent(new Event('myEvent', true));" />

    <mx:TextArea text="{data.notes}" />
</mx:HBox>
```